# Use Java 8 stream to create and a Collection<Stream>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a class

```
class ColumnTags {
    String Name;
    Collection<String> columnSemanticTags;

    // constructor and getter and setters and other relevant attributes
}
```

I want to get the columnSemanticTags from a list of ColumnTags for a given name.

The corresponding method is as follows

```
public Collection<String> getTags(String colName, List<ColumnTags> colList) 
{
   Collection<String> tags = new ArrayList();
   for(ColumnTag col:colList){
        if(colName.equals(col.getName())){
              tags = col.getColumnSemanticTags();
              break;
              }
     }
    return tags;
 }
```

Want to convert the for loop to a java stream . I have tried

```
   tags = colList.stream().filter(col -> colName.equals(col.getName()))
                   .map(col -> col.getColumnSemanticTags())
                   .collect(Collectors.toCollection());
```

I am getting compilation error. I am not aware what should be the Supplier . Have tried ArrayList::new . I have also tried casting it to ArrayList , but no success.
Can someone advice me what am I assuming wrong or what should be the expected way to handle this scenario.
With the solution , can someone explain as to why .collect() is a wrong way of tackling this solution.

Comment: Is there any reason to return a new `ArrayList` if no match was found, rather than a straight-forward `Collections.emptyList()`?

Answer (score 2):

```
public Collection<String> getTags(String colName, List<ColumnTags> colList) {
    return colList.stream().filter(col -> colName.equals(col.getName()))
        .map(col -> col.getColumnSemanticTags())
        .findFirst().orElse(new ArrayList<>());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An easier way of going about this would be to simply filter a `Stream` to find exactly what you're looking for.  If it is found, then return it, otherwise return an empty `ArrayList`:

```
return colList.stream()
              .filter(c -> colName.equals(c.getName()))
              .map(ColumnTag::getColumnSemanticTags)
              .findFirst()
              .orElseGet(ArrayList::new);
```

Comment: Can you explain as to why my attempt was wrong? Why was using .collect() a wrong way into solving this solution.

Comment: When you used `Collectors#toCollection`, it collects the `Stream` into a `Collection<Collection<String>>`, and you only want a `Collection<String>`.

Comment: if I did not have the break; then what should I have used - the flatMap() followed by a collect.

Comment: Removing `break` is equivalent to finding the last element in the `Stream` that shares `colName`, which would be tough to achieve when using a `Stream`.  If you didn't use a `Stream`, you could simply iterate through the `Collection` backwards and break after the first element is found.

Comment: It’s not tough to get the last match instead. Just replace `.findFirst().orElseGet(ArrayList::new);` with `.reduce( (a,b) -> b ) .orElseGet(ArrayList::new);`

Comment: My bad, I didn't realize reduce helped that much!

Comment: This is causing NullPointerException if columnSemanticTags is null .So, have changed the filter to .filter(c -> colName.equals(c.getName()) && c.getColumnSemanticTags!=null) .

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `collect`, you must call `flatMap`. That merges all of the lists (which are come from `map(col -> col.getColumnSemanticTags())`) into a single stream which contains all of the items.

```
 List<String> tags = colList.stream()
                .filter(col -> colName.equals(col.getName()))
                .map(col -> col.getColumnSemanticTags())
                .flatMap(collection -> collection.stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: OP breaks out of the for-loop after the first element is found.

Comment: Thats true, this is just a workaround for using collect().